# Stored Procedure Execution Time vary every few minute

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization, sqlperformance

I have a Stored Procedure to fetch some records from my SQL Server table.

It Executes in 6 minutes first time, and in 4s for consecutive executions.
However, if i wait for around a minute and execute it again, it takes 6 minutes again followed by 4s.

I saved the execution plan for both the slow and fast execution for comparison.
Only difference is that, in slow execution (6 minute) SELECT has a property **ContainsInterleavedExecutionCandidates** = True. Why this property is set and how can i get rid of this...??

Comment: This link explains it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/intelligent-query-processing?view=sql-server-ver15     It even gives a  sample code to disable it via query hint.

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed the CompatibilityLevel to 150. Now first execution takes 2 minutes and consecutive 3s.

Comment: CompileTime and CompileCPU is 1 in the Execution Plan when slow. Problem is that it Compiles every minute. How can I prevent that to happen.